# sourcing multiple modules R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have 5 separate files and I'm trying to source them all in the main app.R file but when I run app.R, I get this error:

Warning: Error in input_ui: could not find function "input_ui"

input_ui is defined in input_module.R and I source input_module.R so I'm not sure the error.

app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinycssloaders)

# Read modules
modules <- dir("modules", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
lapply(modules, source)

source('server.R')
source('ui.R')

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

ui.R

```
ui <- input_ui("data")
```

server.R

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  mydata <- callModule(data_module, "data")
  callModule(input_module, "input_module", mydata)
}
```

input_module.R

```
input_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  plotOutput(ns("plot"))
             
}

input_server <- function(input, output, session, mydata) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot(
    plot(mydata$data)
  )
    
}
```

data_module.R

```
data_module <- function(input, output, session) {
  vals <- reactiveValues()
  vals$data <- mtcars
  return(vals)
}
```

Comment: Why are you choosing to do *both* `app.R` *and* `ui.R`/`server.R`? The `runApp` function looks for both conditions, it seems odd to have them both existing in one directory.

Comment: There are likely scope issues here. I suggest you read https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html (as well as https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html for module organization techniques), and shift towards the use of `global.R`, `ui.R`, and `server.R` (and **not** `app.R`), along with your `modules` directory of modules. I don't know (and cannot test at the moment), but I suspect that if you adhere to the recommended layout of files in the scope-doc, it might work better for you.

Comment: In your app directory, place any R code you'd like sourced in a folder named `R`. All modules, functions, etc., defined in files in the `R` folder will be sourced and available for use in your `app.R` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./modules/input_module.R`

```
inputModuleUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    plotOutput(ns("plot"))
}

inputModuleServer <- function(id, mydata) {
    moduleServer(
        id,
        function(input, output, session) {
            output$plot <- renderPlot(
              plot(mydata()$data)
            )
        }
    )
}
```

`./modules/data_module.R`

```
dataModuleUI <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    NULL
}

dataModuleServer <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(
        id,
        function(input, output, session) {
            vals <- reactiveValues()
            vals$data <- mtcars
            return(vals)
        }
    )
}
```

`./ui.R`

```
ui <- inputModuleUI("input_module")
```

`./server.R`

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
    mydata <- dataModuleServer("data_module")
    inputModuleServer("input_module", reactive(mydata))
}
```

And then running `./app.R` should be fine.